# How to search inside a list and how to call my ToString function? C#

Tags: c#, list, tostring

I'm currently studying the basics of C# and have an assignment where I am supposed to create a librarian that have various methods. Everything is fine and my code is working with some of the methods, but I can't figure out how to 1. Call my ToString method in "Tidskrift" from another method.I've tried creating an instance of "Tidskrift" but it just complains that there is "no argument given that responds to the required formal parameters." I've tried adding them with "Tidskrift(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData)" but then it says that these do not exist in the current context. I've tried defining them again in the method that calls this class but I'm doing something wrong.

My other issue about how to create a method that allows the user to search my list, I have no idea how to write, and I'm having a hard time finding the answer on Google.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace BokHyllan
{
    public class Biblo
    {
        private List<Bok> bokLista = new List<Bok>();
        public void skapaBok()
        {

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t Var god mata in titel: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t");
        string TitelData = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\t Var god mata in författare: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t");
        string FörfattarData = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\t Var god mata in årtal: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t");
        if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int ÅrtalsData)) ;
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktig årtal, använd enbart siffror"); //Bryter loopen vid felaktig input.
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t Ange boktyp: ");
        Console.WriteLine(
                           "\n\t Var god mata in boktyp: " +
                           "\n\t[1] Tidskrift " +
                           "\n\t[2] Roman " +
                           "\n\t[3] Novell"
                           );

        if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int typVal))         // Konverterar input till int.
        {
            if (typVal == 1)
            {

                Tidskrift nyTidskrift = new Tidskrift(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData);            // Genererar ett objekt med underklassen tidskrift.
                bokLista.Add(nyTidskrift);


                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("\n\t Titel: "
                    + TitelData);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t Författare: "
                    + FörfattarData);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tÅrtal: "
                    + ÅrtalsData);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tTyp: "
                    + nyTidskrift.Typ);

            }
            else if (typVal == 2)
            {
                Roman nyRoman = new Roman(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData);            // Genererar ett objekt med underklassen roman.
                bokLista.Add(nyRoman);

                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("\n\tTitel: "
                    + TitelData);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tFörfattare: "
                    + FörfattarData);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tÅrtal: "
                    + ÅrtalsData);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tTyp: "
                    + nyRoman.Typ);
            }
            else if (typVal == 3)
            {
                Novell nyNovell = new Novell(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData);           // Genererar ett objekt med underklassen novel.
                bokLista.Add(nyNovell);

                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("\n\tTitel: "
                    + TitelData);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tFörfattare: "
                    + FörfattarData);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tÅrtal: "
                    + ÅrtalsData);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tTyp: "
                    + nyNovell.Typ);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt inmatning, var god välj 1-3");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }



            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }

    public void VisaBoker()
    {
        
        foreach (Bok item in bokLista)
        {
            
            Tidskrift ts = new Tidskrift(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t Titel: "
                + item.Titel);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t Författare: "
                + item.Författare);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t Årtal: "
                + item.Årtal);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t Typ: "
                + item.Typ + "\n\t");

            Console.WriteLine("\n\t**\n\t");
        }

    }

    public void SokBok()
    {

    }

    public void RaderaBoker()
    {
        bokLista.Clear();

    }

}
public class Bok            // Genererar bokklassen.
{
    public string Titel;
    public string Författare;
    public int Årtal;
    public string Typ;


    public Bok(string TitelData, string FörfattarData, int ÅrtalsData)          // Konstruktor som håller information för klassen.
    {
        Titel = TitelData;
        Författare = FörfattarData;
        Årtal = ÅrtalsData;
        
    }

}


public class Tidskrift : Bok            // Underklass ett.
{
    public Tidskrift(string TitelData, string FörfattarData, int ÅrtalsData) : base(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData)
    {

        Typ = "Tidskrift";
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Typ;
    }
}
public class Roman : Bok               // Underklass två.
{
    public Roman(string TitelData, string FörfattarData, int ÅrtalsData) : base(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData)
    {
        Typ = "Roman";
    }
}
public class Novell : Bok       // Underklass tre.
{
    public Novell(string TitelData, string FörfattarData, int ÅrtalsData) : base(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData)
    {
        Typ = "Novell";
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isRunning = true;
        Biblo bb = new Biblo();
        
        
            
       
        

        while (isRunning)
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t Välkommen till Stadsbibliotekets klassifikationssystem");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t[1] Registrera en ny bok");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t[2] Visa alla böcker");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t[3] Rensa bibliotek");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t[4] Avsluta");



            if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int menyVal))

            {
                switch (menyVal)
                {
                    case 1:             // Lägger till ny bok med användarens input.

                        bb.skapaBok();

                        break;

                    case 2:                                 // Tar fram alla sparade böcker.
                        Console.Clear();
                        bb.VisaBoker();
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Console.Clear();
                        bb.RaderaBoker();
                        Console.WriteLine("Information borttagen");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case 4:                                         // Stänger av programmet.
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\t Tack för du använde Stadsbibliotekets klassifikationssystem");
                        Console.ReadLine();

                        isRunning = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Felaktig inmatning, var god välj 1-4");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm at a loss and have spent two days trying to figure this out. Hope someone can help!

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++? Looks like C#. Did you post the wrong code?

Comment: You are totally right... Spent a month thinking it was C++, took a look at my book now and it's C#. We studied C++ in "Programming 1"(Name of my course) and this is "Programming 2" and I just assumed we would continue on the same. Thank you for pointing that out! I'll change it right now.

Comment: You should have a `ToString` in `Bok`, which you override in the subclasses. Then call that for each book.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that right now! <3 Could you maybe also give me a code example how that might look?

Comment: I commented out this line inside `VisaBoker()` (seemed unnecessary) and it at least compiled: `Tidskrift ts = new Tidskrift(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData);`.

Comment: Yes that's my issue! The code you commented out is me trying to create an instance of Tidsskrift so I can call it's ToString function.

Comment: @FromTellus But *why* are you trying to do that? All the items you want to show are in `bokLista`. You should print each `item`, not create any new objects.

Comment: My assignment tells me that each subclass (Tidsskrift, Roman, Novel) needs to have a ToString method that is used in my for loop to display custom messages for each subclass when the for loop is used.

Comment: See my first comment above - the loop should (more than likely) be like `foreach (Bok item in bokLista) { Console.Write(item.ToString()); }`. And review the introduction to polymorphism in your book.

Comment: *My other issue about how to create a method that allows the user to search my list* - it is best to ask one question per SO question. There isn't really enough detail to know how you want to proceed with that.. But in essence it'll be like VisaBoker, except it will take something to search by; a string search term `public void SearchBoker(string searchTerm)` and then perhaps it will use a loop, and say `foreach(Bok item in bokLista) if(item.Titel.Contains(searchTerm) || item.Typ.Contains(searchTerm) ...`

Comment: Thank you again! I think I can grasp this concept. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but I'm obviously missing something. I wrote the following
         

`public void SokBok(string SearchTerm)
        {
            string SearchTerm = Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (Bok item in bokLista)
            {
                if (item.Titel.Contains(SearchTerm))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Din bok finns" +item.Titel);
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: Mmm.. Nasty as code-in-comments is (code should always be posted in questions).. If you're going to ask for the searchterm inside the method, you don't need the method to take it as a parameter... You've written `SokBok(string SearchTerm)` and you've written `string SearchTerm = Console.ReadLine();` - that'll give a "variable cannot be declared because that name is used in an enclosing scope". remove it from the method so it's `SokBok()` and rename it to `string searchTerm` -> in C# we call variables declared inside methods like `camelCase`, not `PascalCase`

Comment: Worked it out! Thank you all so much!

Comment: Sorry for posting code in the comments T_T You are all too kind with all the help.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I'll deal with the ToString query but see my comment about what to do on your search query...</sub>

Your school class is probably trying to teach you polymorphism.

A `Tidskrift` is-a `Bok`:

```
public class Tidskrift : Bok
```

Your list is full of `Bok`s:

```
List<Bok> bokLista = new List<Bok>();
..

Tidskrift nyTidskrift = new Tidskrift(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData);            
bokLista.Add(nyTidskrift);
..
Roman nyRoman = new Roman(TitelData, FörfattarData, ÅrtalsData);
bokLista.Add(nyRoman);
```

Because, at a basic level, a Roman or a Tidskrift is a Bok, they're allowed in your List. Everything in your List will *look like* a Bok but actually, they will still be a Tidskrift or Roman etc at heart. Whatever they were when they went into the Bok list, they still are.. But unless you cast them back to what they really are, you can only interact with them as if they are a Bok, using facilities (proeprties and methods) that are available on a Bok (or something further up the inheritance chain, like GetHashcode, coming from Object)

---

You have overriden ToString in Tidskrift:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Typ;
    }
```

This means if you call `ToString` on one of the `Bok`s *and that Bok is actually a Tidskrift* then the overridden ToString will be called.

If the thing inside the Bok is actually a Roman, the default ToString will be called (it will be `BokHyllan.Roman` probably). because Roman *does not (yet)* override ToString()

This means, if you want to call `ToString`, just call it on your `Bok item`:

```
    public void VisaBoker()
    {

        foreach (Bok item in bokLista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ToString Says: " + item.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("\n\t Titel: "
            ...
```

ToString is guaranteed to exist for every Bok, because a Bok is an Object*, and Object has a ToString.. but *what ToString does* on a case-by-case basis will depend on whether the thing that the Bok truly is (a Tidskrift, Roman or Novell) has got an `override` of `ToString` or not. If it does have one, it is used. If it doesn't have one, Bok's one is tried (and because Bok doesn't actually have one, Object's one is used; C# goes up the inheritance chain from what the thing truly is, trying to find a ToString it can use. The first one it finds, is used)

- Truly is a Tiskrift

  - ToString found on Tidskrift - use it
- Truly is a Roman

  - Roman has no ToString - try Bok

    - Bok has no ToString - try Object

      - Object has a ToString - use it
- Truly is a Novell

  - Novell has no ToString - try Bok

    - Bok has no ToString - try Object

      - Object has a ToString - use it

<sub>* everything is ultimately an Object; even if it doesn't say `class Bok : object`. If you've said something like `class Tisdkrift:Bok{` that means Tidskrift is a Bok. If you've said `class Bok{` that means the same as `class Bok:object{`. Everything ultimately is something that [is something that..] is an object</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much!! Of course, it was something simple like this. And yes, you are right! My course is currently working with polymorphism.

Now I just need to figure out how to search my list for a specific keyword and I'm more or less done :)

Comment: I dropped a bit of an advice in the comments; copypaste your VisaBoker, add an argument, use the argument while you loop.. and then wire your new method up into the menu (ask for a searchterm like you ask for a Titel). Give it a go and ask a question if you get stuck

Comment: Got the ToString to work like a charm! Thank you so much. I answered your other comment as I am still having issues with the search method.